# Database not opening error qt c++

Tags: c++, database, qt, runtime-error

I have created a class named MainWIndow which has a method(getconnOpen) to provide database connection!  following is my code!

MainWindow.h

```
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
Q_OBJECT
public:

 QSqlDatabase mydb;

bool getconnOpen(QString uname,QString pword,QString ip,int port,QString dbname){
    mydb=QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QOCI");
    mydb.setUserName(uname);
    mydb.setPassword(pword);
    mydb.setHostName(ip);
    mydb.setPort(port);
    mydb.setDatabaseName(dbname);

mydb.open
return true;
}

public:
explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
~MainWindow();

private slots:
void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
Ui::MainWindow *ui;

};
```

MainWindow.cpp

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

Dialog *dialog1=new Dialog(this);
if(getconnOpen(ui->lineEdit->text(),ui->lineEdit_2->text(),ui->lineEdit_3->text(),ui->lineEdit_4->text().toInt(),ui->lineEdit_5->text()){
    dialog1->show();
}

}
```

Dialog.h

```
class Dialog : public QDialog
{

Q_OBJECT

public:QSqlDatabase mydb;
public:
explicit Dialog(QWidget *parent = 0);

~Dialog();

private slots:
void on_pushButton_clicked();
```

Dialog.cpp

```
void Dialog::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
QSqlQueryModel modal = new QSqlQueryModel();
QSqlQuery qry=new QSqlQuery(mydb);

qry->prepare("select User FROM USERS");
qry->exec();
modal->setQuery(*qry);
ui->tableView->setModel(modal);

}
```

Though I opened the connection in MainWindow.h  the query in dialog.cpp gives an error stating "database not open" ! But I opened the databse in MainWindow.cpp! How can I correct this?

Comment: How do you know it successfully opened? Did you debug the code? Your function getConnectionOpen always returns true.. why bother with a return value if it will always be true? Just an observation.

Comment: @rob I previously created ran the query on Mainwindow.cpp it gave the result in to a tableview! But I won't the table view on another window(dialog.cpp)

Comment: the Dialog has its own "uninitialized" instance of mydb. You need to pass it in from the Mainwindow object for it to be able to use it, or make it available somehow.. the way it is the MainWindow::mydb is open but the Dialog::mydb is not open. unless the constructor to Dialog does this?

Comment: @Rob Thanx alot! Can you give an idea about how to pass it? I googled but could not find any clue :(

Comment: You already pass the main window to the constructor of the Dialog. So you can remove mydb from the Dialog and just use the parent.. I suspect Dialog keeps a pointer to its parent? then get the mydb from the parent. Not sure of the interfaces. either it has a member called parent or a getParent function

Comment: @Rob  Dialog does have a pointer to the parent ( I assume you mean having Dialog *dialog1 = new Dialog(this) ) But I don't know how to get mydb from the parent(MainWindow.cpp)

Comment: Make mydb static then and have a static method to access it. that way you can do MainWindow::getMyDb() or something. if you want the mainwindow to manage that instance.

Comment: @rob Do I have to make any changes to the Dialog.cpp constructor to create parent child relationship?

Comment: just keep a pointer to the parent MainWindow. and use that to access the mydb from the parent..

Comment: I am trying to find a way to better do this.. this is ugly.

Comment: try doing QSqlQuery qry=new QSqlQuery(dynamic_cast<MainWindow>(parentWidget())->mydb) in the dialog code.

Comment: @rob thanx but does not return anything the same database not open error occurs :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this (mind you I do not have time to test this so you may need to tweak it) And I am annoyed that it created a cyclical dependence between the MainWindow and Dialog.. you can undo that by creating a dbmanager class or using a shared pointer to the mydb instead. but this is the quickest thing I could type for you without having to redesign all your code.

MainWindow.h

```
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
   QSqlDatabase mydb;


   bool getconnOpen(QString uname,QString pword,QString ip,int port,QString dbname){
      mydb=QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QOCI");
      mydb.setUserName(uname);
      mydb.setPassword(pword);
      mydb.setHostName(ip);
      mydb.setPort(port);
      mydb.setDatabaseName(dbname);

      // Return the actual state of the db instead of return true.
      return mydb.open();
   }

public:
   explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
   ~MainWindow();

private slots:
   void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
   Ui::MainWindow *ui;

};
```

MainWindow.cpp

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

Dialog *dialog1=new Dialog(this);
if(getconnOpen(ui->lineEdit->text(),ui->lineEdit_2->text(),ui->lineEdit_3->text(),ui->lineEdit_4->text().toInt(),ui->lineEdit_5->text()){
    dialog1->show();
}

}
```

Dialog.h

```
class Dialog : public QDialog
{

Q_OBJECT

public:
explicit Dialog(QWidget *parent = 0);

~Dialog();

private slots:
void on_pushButton_clicked();
```

Dialog.cpp

```
void Dialog::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
   QSqlQueryModel modal = new QSqlQueryModel();
   // get the db object from the parent widget, if the parent widget returned is not of the MainWindow type then dynamic_cast will return NULL.
   MainWindow *mainWindow = dynamic_cast<MainWindow(parentWidget());

   // if all went well then mainWindow is not NULL but should test first.
   if (mydb != NULL)
   {
      QSqlQuery qry=new QSqlQuery(mainWindow->mydb);

      qry->prepare("select User FROM USERS");
      qry->exec();
      modal->setQuery(*qry);
      ui->tableView->setModel(modal);
   }
   // do something else if the pointer is NULL.
}
```

I am not happy with doing it this way:

*********** OK FOUND THE RIGHT WAY TO DO IT I THINK!*********************
from this post [Handling QSqlDatabase connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25483218/handling-qsqldatabase-connections)

looks like QSqlDatabase is already a connection manager so you add the connection once and retrieve it by name from your other form. Again I do not have the ability to test this but this would be a better approach as it uses the QT connection manager as it is intended and there are no cyclical dependencies between MainWindow and the Dialog.

MainWindow.h

```
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
   QSqlDatabase mydb;


   bool getconnOpen(QString uname,QString pword,QString ip,int port,QString dbname){
      // Add the database by name so you can retrieve it later. I would also 
      // not hardcode the name like this but this.. yuck but hey you can fix
      // that yourself ;)
      mydb=QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QOCI", "MyDbConnection");
      mydb.setUserName(uname);
      mydb.setPassword(pword);
      mydb.setHostName(ip);
      mydb.setPort(port);
      mydb.setDatabaseName(dbname);

      // Return the actual state of the db instead of return true.
      return mydb.open();
   }

public:
   explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
   ~MainWindow();

private slots:
   void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
   Ui::MainWindow *ui;

};
```

MainWindow.cpp

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

Dialog *dialog1=new Dialog(this);
if(getconnOpen(ui->lineEdit->text(),ui->lineEdit_2->text(),ui->lineEdit_3->text(),ui->lineEdit_4->text().toInt(),ui->lineEdit_5->text()){
    dialog1->show();
}

}
```

Dialog.h

```
class Dialog : public QDialog
{

Q_OBJECT

public:
explicit Dialog(QWidget *parent = 0);

~Dialog();

private slots:
void on_pushButton_clicked();
```

Dialog.cpp

```
void Dialog::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
   QSqlQueryModel modal = new QSqlQueryModel();

   // make sure the database exists.
   if (QSqlDatabase::contains("MyDbConnection");)
   {
      // retrieve the database by name from the database manager.
      QSqlQuery qry=new QSqlQuery(QSqlDatabase::database("MyDbConnection"));

      qry->prepare("select User FROM USERS");
      qry->exec();
      modal->setQuery(*qry);
      ui->tableView->setModel(modal);
   }
   // do something else if the pointer is NULL.
}
```

Comment: Thanx alot mate I'll try this and see! Btw why aren't you happy with this?